# No route matches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-routing, rails-api

I'm getting a "No route matches" exception in one of my tests (and using curl from the command line) one of my routes (POST /users/confirm). The curl's I've tried are as follows, neither of them work and receive the same exceptions outlined in the below notes:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; version=1" \
   -d '{ user: { "token":"1deb36b4e6a7ba6d9203" } }' \
   http://localhost:3000/appname/users/confirm

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; version=1" \
   -d '{ "token":"1deb36b4e6a7ba6d9203" }' \
   http://localhost:3000/appname/users/confirm
```

[image]

My test is as follows. I have `config.wrap_parameters = true` in my /config/application.rb file...

[image]

Here is my User UsersController#confirm action along with my strong params. I `params.require(:user).permit(:token)` as opposed to simply `params.permit(:token)` because, as stated above, I have `config.wrap_parameters = true` in my /config/application.rb file...

[image]

This is my route entry...

[image]

Here is the output from `rails routes` (app name removed)...

[image]

I have `config.wrap_parameters = true` in my /config/application.rb file...

[image]

Oddly enough, if I change my params in my test to `post :confirm, params: { token: @user.confirmation_token }`, I get the following error instead:
[image]

At a loss. Any thoughts?

Comment: According to the results of `rails routes` your path is incomplete. It expects something after `/confirm`. For example, `/confirm/username` will be a valid route.

Comment: Please dont post an images, post actual text.

Comment: @Зелёный 6 and 1/2 dozen to another. Some people like images. Sheez.

Comment: @YawBoakye thank you, it appears I didn't need the :token param after all, you helped me on my way rather than worrying about me posting images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't need :token in my route after all. Changed it to this, and all is well:

post '/appname/users/confirm/', to: 'users#confirm', as: 'appname_users_confirm'